# echarts for react save chart png in different resolution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I'm using https://github.com/hustcc/echarts-for-react

Desktop:
[image]
Mobile
[image]

When you click on the Save Icon the chart will be saved as you see, on mobile you will have less items/information than a desktop version.

I'm now looking for a way to export the Pie with a specific resolution, my problem is on mobile phones the pie is so small you don't see anything and i want to give the user the possible to export a bigger chart with more info. (which happens when the chart would be rendered in a higher resolution like 1920x1080).

I found a workaround, but this seems not a good solution, is rendering the chart 2 times (1 time in the FHD) and hide the second one so I can get a big image with all info i want. (see function gettest()

The problem: background is transparency.

Im also looking for 2 possibles solutions.

1.: use the saveas or other to export/rerender in 1920x1080 or
2.: add a white background to my hidden chart to export it over the workaround

I would prefer solution 1 but in the docs i haven't found anything like this.

Thanks in advance.

```
      const option = {
           title: {
               text: '',
               subtext: '',
               left: 'center'
           },

           tooltip: {
               trigger: 'item'
           },
           toolbox: {
               feature: {

                   saveAsImage: {
                       backgroundColor: '#fff'
                   }
               }
           },

           series: [
               {
                   name: '',
                   type: 'pie',
                   radius:  window.innerWidth < 1366 ? '50%' : '90%',
                   data: [
                       {
                           "value": 190.77828000000002,
                           "name": "Xtrackers FTSE Vietnam Swap UCITS ETF 1C"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 190.70976,
                           "name": "Franklin FTSE India UCITS ETF USD Acc"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 190.848,
                           "name": "Xtrackers MSCI Thailand UCITS ETF 1C"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 493.81046,
                           "name": "VanEck Video Gaming and eSports UCITS ETF A USD"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 462.71727,
                           "name": "Global X Video Games & Esports UCITS ETF"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 695.53755,
                           "name": "Vanguard FTSE All-World UCITS ETF"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 1748.34265,
                           "name": "BASF"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 1233.9791,
                           "name": "Niu Tech ADR-A"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 377.74,
                           "name": "AT&T"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 359.4,
                           "name": "Sixt SE Inhaber-Vorzugsakt. o.St.o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 735.0396000000001,
                           "name": "Mercedes-Benz Group AG Namens-Aktien o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 901.6200000000001,
                           "name": "Ströer SE & Co. KGaA Inhaber-Aktien o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 209.99468,
                           "name": "Covestro AG Inhaber-Aktien o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 280.64384,
                           "name": "British American Tobacco PLC Registered Shares LS -,25"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 1776.78144,
                           "name": "Allianz SE vink.Namens-Aktien o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 1156.9427999999998,
                           "name": "Unilever PLC Registered Shares LS -,031111"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 1328.84396,
                           "name": "HeidelbergCement AG Inhaber-Aktien o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 692.69928,
                           "name": "Volkswagen AG Vorzugsaktien o.St. o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 855.93475,
                           "name": "Deutsche Post AG Namens-Aktien o.N."
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 1327.5,
                           "name": "Daimler Truck"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 745.01694,
                           "name": "Lang & Schwarz N"
                       },
                       {
                           "value": 324.2454,
                           "name": "GSK Rg"
                       }
                   ],
                   emphasis: {
                       itemStyle: {
                           shadowBlur: 10,
                           shadowOffsetX: 0,
                           shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                       }
                   },
                   label: {
                       formatter: '{b}: {d}%'}
               },

           ],

       };
       
       
         function gettest(){

           const echartInstance = echartRef.current.getEchartsInstance();
           const base64 = echartInstance.getDataURL();
           var link = document.createElement("a");
           link.download = "Chart";
           link.href = base64;
           document.body.appendChild(link);
           link.click();
           document.body.removeChild(link);
       }
       return (
       
        <ReactECharts
                option={option}
                theme={"vintage"}

                style={{ height: window.innerWidth < 1366 ? "200px" : "500px" }}/>


//my try with hidding the second chart where my background has transparency but i want white
            <ReactECharts
                option={option}
                theme={"vintage"}
                ref={(e) => { echartRef.current = e; }}
                style={{ height: "1080px", width:"1920px", display:"none", backgroundColor:"red" }}/>
            <div onClick={(e) => gettest(e)}>FHD Speichern</div>
            
            )
```

Comment: Take a look here: [https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.getDataURL](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.getDataURL)

Comment: @AdalcinoJunior ah nice this work, maybe someone knows a solution for the direct way, if not i have to deal with this